# Cannot get parameters off url in POST request php

Tags: php

I Have a url here which I am using to send a post request to my server and I want to catch the `EventType`, `RessourceId`, and `Date`, and put their values in a array if possible.
 I am trying so many methods but for some reason I cannot get those information.

Here is the url

```
//POST
  https://localhost/hello/index.php/kyc_succeeded_hook?EventType=SUCCEEDED&RessourceId=1309853&Date=1397037093
```

I used first this method,

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
        var_dump($data);
     //I get nothing back.
```

Then I tried this

```
$Query_String  = explode("&", explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1] );
     var_dump($Query_String);
```

I get values back like this in postman if I echo it

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
    <b>array</b>
    <i>(size=3)</i>
  0
    <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font>
    <small>string</small>
    <font color='#cc0000'>'EventType=SUCCEEDED'</font>
    <i>(length=23)</i>
  1
    <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font>
    <small>string</small>
    <font color='#cc0000'>'RessourceId=1309853'</font>
    <i>(length=19)</i>
  2
    <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font>
    <small>string</small>
    <font color='#cc0000'>'Date=1397037093'</font>
    <i>(length=15)</i>
</pre>
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
    <small>string</small>
    <font color='#cc0000'>''</font>
    <i>(length=0)</i>
</pre>
```

I am not sure how to put those values in a array.

Comment: You send those parameters as http `GET` arguments. Therefore you can simply access them using the `$_GET` superglobal variable.

Comment: A few hours with the PHP manual and this would not be an issue or a question. SO is not supposed to replace reading the manual or a couple of good books or tutorials

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know how get and post works, I was using a APi made by someone else to get the response and it was stated use a POST request, which messed up my head...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query string variables that are appended to the url of the page are always seen as get variables, so you will need to use the [`$_GET`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array to find them.

So, to get the EventType, you can do the following:

```
$eventType = $_GET['EventType'];
```

If you want all get and post variables in one array, you can use the [`$_REQUEST`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) array.

Answer (score 0):

Your http method is get so You Have to use `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`.try below:

```
echo $_GET['EventType'];// same for others it will print SUCCESS

echo $_REQUEST['EventType'];// same for others it will print SUCCESS
```